# how to draw lines between two divs in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, line

I am developing a tree for MLM concept.

I have worked for displaying the tree fetched from database showing user hierarchy. Now I would like to connect parent with its children. It is a binary tree so each parent has two children.

My code is at JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7u9L1bfx/

And CSS at Jsfiddle

```
<center>
  <div style='width:60%'>
    <div class='user' id='1'>
      <p> 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div class='col2 child' id='1'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col2 child' id='1'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div class='col3 child' id='2'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col3 child' id='2'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col3 child' id='5'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col3 child' id='5'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>8</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='3'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='3'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='4'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='4'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='6'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>7</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='6'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='8'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col4 child' id='8'>
      <div class='user'>
        <p>Blank</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
  </div>
</center>
```

[image]

I need a css / javascript / jquery function that can simply draw lines. I will put it into the loop myself.

Comment: Do you mean an horizontal separator line ?

Comment: You have multiple element with the same id, that is not good

Comment: I will convert ids into classes. can you please tell me how we can draw cross lines connecting parent with its two children???

Comment: @scaisEdge I need to join parent with its two children like in binary tree.

Comment: Lots of data visualization libraries around you can use to do this with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real option your going to have is to use a `<canvas>`. You can stack all of your elements on top of a large canvas, then you'll have to calculate their positions and draw lines.

Your HTML will look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Then you'll have to size the container and canvas to the same, then position your divs on top of that. Then using combinations of the div's `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft`, you'll have to figure out their position then use the `canvas` draw functions to draw the lines.

This will give you a basic approach. Take a stab at creating the code and you can post another answer if you get stuck.

Another alternative would be to use `<hr>` elements and the `transform` CSS property to rotate and position, but that math would be pretty annoying to work out and still wouldn't be as clean as the canvas approach.

Answer (score -2):

One possibility to draw lines is the `<hr>` tag.

[HR Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

Comment: I am aware of HR tag but I am looking for the solution to connect two divs with a cross line.